# updating a state inside a map, causes to push new elements to state that I don't want

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, checkbox, array.prototype.map

here I have data state which I'm trying to loop over it with map function, and print out checklist which I called myChecklist.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id:0,
      isChecked: true
    },
    {
      id:1,
      isChecked: false
    },
    {
      id:2,
      isChecked: false
    },
  ])
  

  const myCheckList = data.map((checkbox, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <input type="checkbox" 
          checked={checkbox.isChecked} 
          onChange={e => {setData(prev => [...prev, prev[index].isChecked = e.target.checked])}} 
          id={index} />
        <label htmlFor={index}>{checkbox.id}</label>
      </div>
    )
  })

  console.log(data)

  return (
    <div>{myCheckList}</div>
  )
}

export default App
```

every time I click my any of the checkboxes, it updates to ***isChecked*** Boolean referring to that checkbox. the problem is pushes new elements to the ***data*** state which cause the to ***map*** function to create a new checkbox I don't want. when ever I click the my checkboxes the log of **data  **state should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "isChecked": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "isChecked": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "isChecked": false
    }
]
```

but after changing the checkbox a couple of times it would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "isChecked": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "isChecked": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "isChecked": false
    },
    false,
    true
]
```

noticed some true false values pushed to the state. I am NOT pushing anyThing so why this happens ????

I'll appreciate your help. thanks

I tried to separate the state that I am mapping throw and the state I want to update like this

````
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {

  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([
    {isChecked: false},
    {isChecked: false},
    {isChecked: false}
  ])

  const data = [
    {
      id:0,
    },
    {
      id:1,
    },
    {
      id:2,
    },
  ]


  const myCheckList = data.map((checkbox, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <input type="checkbox" 
          checked={isChecked[index].isChecked} 
          onChange={e => {setIsChecked(prev => [...prev, prev[index].isChecked = e.target.checked])}} 
          id={index} />
        <label htmlFor={index}>{checkbox.id}</label>
      </div>
    )
  })

  console.log(isChecked)

  return (
    <div id='my-id'>{myCheckList}</div>
  )
}

export default App```

no new checkboxes would be printed to DOM but the issue of pushing elements I don't to the state, still remains
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "isChecked": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "isChecked": true
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "isChecked": false
    }
]
```

If you want an output like this, there is a problem with your code.  Particularly this line

```
          onChange={e => {setData(prev => [...prev, prev[index].isChecked = e.target.checked])}}
```

What are you doing here is, you are appending to prev array, and the object that you are entering is a bool (whose logic is wrong).

Correct way would be to first determing the index of check box which is changed, and then flip is `isChecked` value.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      isChecked: true,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      isChecked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      isChecked: false,
    },
  ]);
  const handleCheckboxChange = (index) => {
    setData((prev) => {
      return prev.map((checkbox, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          return {
            ...checkbox,
            isChecked: !checkbox.isChecked,
          };
        }
        return checkbox;
      });
    });
  };

  const myCheckList = data.map((checkbox, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checkbox.isChecked}
            onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(index)}
          id={index}
        />
        <label htmlFor={index}>{checkbox.id}</label>
      </div>
    );
  });

  console.log(data);

  return <div>{myCheckList}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Sorry for the beginner question

Comment: Well you can mark it as the correct ans if it helped 